# VBA Macro for fill random Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

i have some 10,000 records in excel file. i want to put random dates for those 10,000 records. Random dates i will give manaully.

For Ex:-

```
Random dates:- 01-OCt-15 to 30-Oct-15

Emp id   Emp Name Sal_Date
  101     JOhn     05-OCt-15
  102     Mathew   07-OCt-15
  103     Stephen  26-Oct-15
  105     Rahul    05-oct-15
```

like this..............

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't really requires VBA.

1. put your start and end dates in two cells
2. in first cell of "sal_date" enter:
   `=RANDBETWEEN(<start_date>,<end-date>)`

   - format this cell with the date format you need
3. go to the first cell of "emp name"
4. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> - this will go to the last row of your data
5. press <kbd>right</kbd> to go to "sal_date" column
6. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> - now your whole column is selected
7. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - this fills down the formula
8. if you want to convert formulas to constant values: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then in ribbon select paste - values

Answer (score 1):

In some cell enter:

```
=DATE(2015,10,RANDBETWEEN(1,30))
```

and copy down

If you need to do this as part of a larger macro then:

```
Sub DateFiller()
   Range("A1:A10000").Formula = "=DATE(2015,10,RANDBETWEEN(1,30))"
End Sub
```